# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this3.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am getting above error while setting the data in state in reactjs,

Scenario: passing data from child component to parent component, in child component I am calling parent function and changing the state value using setstate,

ChildComponent

```
search(){
        var input = this.refs.userInput.value;
        this.props.findSearch(input);
        input.value = '';       
    }
```

Parent Component:

```
findSearch(input){
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/blogs`)
  .then(res => {
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let rest = res.data.filter((e)=>{    
      e.cardtitle === input;
    });
    this.setState({result:rest}); // here I am getting the error
  })
}
```

can you please help me out or other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Bind function to this context in your react component.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.findSearch = this.findSearch.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a [`this` context related issue](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

You should `bind` your function to the `class` with `this` or just use an arrow function as a class field to get a lexical context for `this`:

```
findSearch = (input) => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/blogs`)
  .then(res => {
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let rest = res.data.filter((e)=>{    
      e.cardtitle === input;
    });
    this.setState({result:rest}); // here I am getting the error
  })
}
```

Note that class fields are a proposal in stage 3 and you would likely need to add [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties)